# Printing BST Formatted Output

Tags: tree, format, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to print a binary search tree and get the following output:

-19->4->5->6->259->

How do I adjust the traverse function so that the last arrow is not printed in the output?

I am using this code inside the main function:

```
Tree x = new Tree(5);
x.add(6);
x.add(4);
x.add(259);
x.add(-19);
x.traverse(x);
```

The Tree class is below:

```
public class Tree {
    Tree root;
    Tree left;
    Tree right;
    int value; 

public Tree(int value){
    this.value=value;
    this.left=null;
    this.right=null;
}

boolean add(int value){

    if (value == this.value)
        return false;
    else if (value <this.value) {
        if (left == null) {
            left = new Tree(value);
            return true;
        } else
            return left.add(value);
    } else if (value > this.value) {
        if (right == null) {
            right = new Tree(value);
            return true;
        } else
            return right.add(value);
    }
    return false;

}

void traverse(Tree root){

    if (root.left != null){
        traverse(root.left);
    }       

    System.out.printf("%d",root.value);
    System.out.printf("->");
    if (root.right != null){
        traverse(root.right);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The output is now -1945->6->259

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid printing the `->` only for the last, i.e., biggest, element. So, you want to not print it if the node has no right child and all nodes leading to it were "right" nodes.

```
void traverse(Tree root, boolean allRight){

    if (root.left != null){
        traverse(root.left, false);
    }       

    System.out.printf("%d",root.value);
    if(!allRight || root.right != null)
        System.out.printf("->");
    if (root.right != null){
        traverse(root.right, allRight);
    }
}
```

Also, you would now call it like this : `x.traverse(x, true)`.

Comment: The output is now -1945->6->259

Comment: @user40680 Hope that fixed it.

Comment: The second parameter in the second recursive call to traverse is true. That fixed it Thanks!

Comment: It should be `allRight`. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version

```
public boolean traverse(TreeNode root){

    if (root.left != null){
        traverse(root.left);
        System.out.printf("->");

    }       

    System.out.printf("%d",root.value);

    if (root.right != null){
        System.out.printf("->");
        traverse(root.right);           
    }

    return true;
}
```